# Wait for file program failed due to %Counter% LSS %Limit%

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /A Counter = 0
SET /A Limit = 5

:File_Check
IF EXIST D:\Automation\OTOT_OBAL\Automation\myfilter.jar ( 

            GOTO Trigger_Found
            ) 

               ELSE IF %Counter% LSS %Limit% (
                                           timeout /t 5 /nobreak >null
                                           SET /A Counter = Counter + 1
                                           GOTO File_Check
                                             ) 

                     GOTO (VERYEND)


ENDLOCAL

:Trigger_Found
echo ON
echo TRIGGER FOUND
Exit

:VERYEND
echo !Counter!
echo program has reached maximum wait time we are going to exit.
Exit
```

Answer (score 0):

The `else` is redundant, but if used **must** be on the same physical line as the preceding `)`

The target of the final `goto` is the label `(veryend)` not the label `veryend`.

---

In the absence of current code:

```
IF EXIST D:\Automation\OTOT_OBAL\Automation\myfilter.jar ( 
 GOTO Trigger_Found
) ELSE IF %Counter% LSS %Limit% (
 timeout /t 5 /nobreak >null
 SET /A Counter = Counter + 1
 GOTO File_Check
) 

GOTO VERYEND
```

should work

```
IF EXIST D:\Automation\OTOT_OBAL\Automation\myfilter.jar GOTO Trigger_Found
IF %Counter% LSS %Limit% (
 timeout /t 5 /nobreak >null
 SET /A Counter = Counter + 1
 GOTO File_Check
) 

GOTO VERYEND
```

would probably be better.

Comment: The script worked but it complained about the ELSE as not recognized. How to rewrite this code without ELSE ?